# Issue with Graphql query using graphlient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using graphlient gem to make a graphql query call
I have to make this call in controller so thats why I am using graphlient ta make call

```
client = Graphlient::Client.new("http://localhost:3000/graphql", headers: {
            'Authorization': "API #{api_key}"
          })

response = client.query do
      query{
           search(id: 1){
            
                edges{
                    node{
                         id
                         name
                         timing{
                            start
                            end
                          }
                         }
                      }   
                  }
       end
```

I have timing field which has two attribute **start** and **end** but Rails is giving me syntax error as

> end is a keyword in Rails

How can I run this query without syntax error? Is there any way to send the query in string format to run this?

Comment: According to the docs, you can use string, why not use it? So it will not conflict with the reserved words.

Comment: Can you please share the example or link with me  to check how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using [ashkan18/graphlient](https://github.com/ashkan18/graphlient) since this is the first result when searching for graphlient.

And according to its documentation, you can use a string for making queries. So instead of using blocks in your example, you can do this instead:

```
response = client.query <<~GRAPHQL
  query {
    search(id: 1) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          timing {
            start
            end
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
GRAPHQL
```